# Getting confint to work with the rms lrm object

Tags: r, glm

I can't get the logistic regression from the rms package to work with confint(), here's an example:

```
library(rms)
data(mtcars)
dd <- datadist(mtcars)
options(datadist = "dd")
fit <- lrm(am ~ gear + mpg, data=mtcars)
confint(fit)
```

This gives the error:

> Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

And the traceback() gives:

```
4: profile.glm(object, which = parm, alpha = (1 - level)/4, trace = trace)
3: profile(object, which = parm, alpha = (1 - level)/4, trace = trace)
2: confint.glm(fit)
1: confint(fit)
```

I guess the confint isn't implemented for the lrm() model.

### My question

Is there a convenient alternative to way? Is there some other alternative created for the rms package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
> summary(fit)[ , c("Lower 0.95", "Upper 0.95")]
               Lower 0.95   Upper 0.95
gear        -6.148918e+01 9.756505e+01
 Odds Ratio  1.975094e-27 2.354854e+42
mpg         -1.063706e+00 6.028564e+00
 Odds Ratio  3.451743e-01 4.151185e+02
```

(These results suggest complete separation or some other modeling pathology.)

Answer (score 5):

`confint.default(fit)` appears to work.  Note that it is constructing Wald confidence intervals rather than the more accurate *profile* confidence intervals that `confint.glm()` produces ...

`class(fit)`; `methods(class="lrm")`; `methods(class="rms")` don't suggest any obvious replacements ...

You might look into `bootcov()` and friends for bootstrap confidence intervals (but I haven't got these working yet ...)